# Como realizar uma multiplicação acumulada de valores no R?

Tags: r

Estou fazendo um trabalho de conjuntura econômica, mas travei em uma parte que preciso calcular o valor acumulado das variações entre os meses (de mensais para trimestrais). Este é o código:

```
library(sidrar)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

teste <- get_sidra(api = "/t/3653/n1/all/v/3134/p/last%2032/c544/129314,129315,129316/d/v3134%201")

industrias <- teste %>%
  rename(Setores = 'Seções e atividades industriais (CNAE 2.0)') %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_date(`Mês (Código)`, format='%Y%m')) %>%
  select(Valor, Setores, date) %>% spread(key = Setores, value = Valor) %>%
  rename(Indústria_geral = '1 Indústria geral') %>%
  rename(Indústrias_extrativas = '2 Indústrias extrativas') %>%
  rename(Indústrias_de_transformação = '3 Indústrias de transformação') %>%
  mutate(Var_m_industria_geral = (Indústria_geral/lag(Indústria_geral,1))) %>%
  mutate(Var_m_industria_extrativa = (Indústrias_extrativas/lag(Indústrias_extrativas,1))) %>%
  mutate(Var_m_industria_trans = (Indústrias_de_transformação/lag(Indústrias_de_transformação,1)))
```

Não consegui inserir a tabela aqui, ainda estou aprendendo a manipular. Em síntese, eu gostaria de realizar a multiplicação dos trimestres, "janeiro de 2019 * fevereiro de 2019 * março de 2019" e, após, "abril de 2019 * maio de 2019 * junho de 2019".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Pacotes

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Banco de exemplo

x <- seq.Date(dmy("01/01/21"),dmy("01/12/21"),by = "1 month")
y <- seq(1:12)

df <-
  tibble(
    x = x,
    y = y
  )

#Como fazer

df %>% 
  #Criar variável de trimestre
  mutate(trimestre = quarter(x)) %>% 
  #Agrupando por trimestre
  group_by(trimestre) %>% 
  #Produto acumulado por trimestre
  mutate(produto_tri = cumprod(y))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   trimestre [4]
   x              y trimestre produto_tri
   <date>     <int>     <int>       <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01     1         1           1
 2 2021-02-01     2         1           2
 3 2021-03-01     3         1           6
 4 2021-04-01     4         2           4
 5 2021-05-01     5         2          20
 6 2021-06-01     6         2         120
 7 2021-07-01     7         3           7
 8 2021-08-01     8         3          56
 9 2021-09-01     9         3         504
10 2021-10-01    10         4          10
11 2021-11-01    11         4         110
12 2021-12-01    12         4        1320
```

Comment: Consegui arrumar os dados com o seu código, Vinícius. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Que bom @Bruno, se puder feche a pergunta selecionando a resposta. Isso facilita em futuras buscas!